# PHP method not showing up in xdebug trace output, yet debugger stops at breakpoint in method

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

I've started working on a large PHP project that was built using Zend Framework 2.  In trying to understand the code, I set up xdebug for both debugging within Eclipse and to output tracing of function calls.  The problem is, I can't find certain methods in the trace file that I am almost 100% sure are being called.  So I set a breakpoint within one of those methods in Eclipse, and sure enough, when I reload the page in the browser, execution halts at that breakpoint, so I know that method is being called.  However, I can't find that method being called anywhere within the trace file that was just generated for that page load.  Can anyone help explain this discrepancy?

Here is my xdebug (using v2.2.3) config from php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 1  
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"  
xdebug.remote_mode="req"  
xdebug.remote_port=7800  
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"  
xdebug.collect_params = 3  
xdebug.trace_format = 0  
xdebug.auto_trace = On
```